# transferring from plesk to cpanel

Tags: cpanel, plesk, webmail, mailenable

I would be really glad if someone explains me how to transfer my website from plesk to cpanel, I have no idea what to do.

and what's gonna happen to my webmail?

can I create a new email in my new host and keep my last email on the old host? cause I can't get backup of it, 
or is there any easy way to transfer my current mail too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know, that cPanel offers "complimentary migration service for migrations from Linux versions of Odin Plesk (formerly Parallels) / DirectAdmin / Ensim, to cPanel."?

You are able to inform yourself at for example:

=> https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/cPanel+Migration+Services+and+Guides